# I `have` heard about or I `had` heard about?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, expressions

I asked a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/420992/255062) just now

> I did hear about the interview somewhere else, but I cannot find the original data

I heard about the interview not today, not yesterday, many years ago.

I have know idea about the detail of the interview.

I am not sure if the interview really happened.

In this context, which expression is more appropriate?

1. I did hear about the interview.
2. I have heard about the interview.
3. I had heard about the interview.

Comment: have heard ....

Comment: They are all appropriate barring further context.

Comment: @JasonBassford What kind of context?

Comment: For example: "***Didn't*** you hear about the interview?" "Why, yes. *I **did** hear about the interview.*" The structure used in the answer would generally match the structure used in the question. (The second two versions would normally not be said in that context. But if the question were phrased like one of them instead, then it would be more likely to hear that other version.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for that example. So, this version "**Have** you hear about the interview?" "Why, yes. I have heard about the interview." is also legitimate?

Comment: That's right. You could do the same for the third too. But that's just one method of framing it. If you've written other sentences (not just questions) using a particular tense, you'd be likely to follow with them using same tense.